# Pentaho running job through command line

Tags: java, command-line, pentaho

I have a pentaho job which runs successfully in pentaho but if i try to run the same through command line i get the error

**Kitchen can't continue because the job could not be loaded.**

```
D:\data-integration>kitchen.bat /file:D:\PENTAHO\pentahojobsNtrans_1\jobs\vws_sync_job_2.kjb /level:Basic
DEBUG: Using JAVA_HOME
DEBUG: _PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jre7
DEBUG: _PENTAHO_JAVA=C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe
2014/08/25 12:44:33 - Kitchen - Logging is at level : Basic logging
2014/08/25 12:44:33 - Kitchen - Start of run.
ERROR: Kitchen can't continue because the job couldn't be loaded.
```

What is that i am doing wrong?
please help

Comment: Try to use `/` for the separator inside the filename: `D:/PENTAHO/pentahojobsNtrans_1/jobs/vws_sync_job_2.kjb`

Comment: thanks for quick reply..But the same error i get even after i use / as separator

Comment: got it running! you were right..while adding / i added extra space..Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most common mistake that the begginers do (I am included) is to use "\" to give the path of the transformation or the job. Replace it by "/".

Answer (score 1):

I get the same error on Windows (maybe de same solution works on Linux) because I have **spaces on file names**. If it is your case, protect the entire path of file directory with quotation marks.

For example:

```
"C:\Program Files\Pentaho Data Integration - Kettle 6.1.0.1\kitchen.bat" /file:"C:/Users/Username/Documents/Pentaho Projects/Job - System Integration.kjb" /level:Basic
```

Another important thing is to follow the instruction given by a_horse_with_no_name (funny username by the way) using slash.

Avoid the backslash instruction as given in the kitchen documentation (http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Kitchen+User+Documentation) on its example: `kitchen.bat /file:D:\Jobs\updateWarehouse.kjb /level:Basic`